# list's iterator is implementing both Kotlin.Collection.Iterator as well as Java.util.Iterator?

Tags: java, kotlin, iterator

I have this code

```
        val list = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
        list.iterator().forEachRemaining{}
```

When I check `iterator()` return type, it is returning `iterator` of type from `Kotlin.collections` package

```
public interface Iterator<out T> {
    /**
     * Returns the next element in the iteration.
     */
    public operator fun next(): T

    /**
     * Returns `true` if the iteration has more elements.
     */
    public operator fun hasNext(): Boolean
}
```

From the above, there's no `forEachRemaining{}` function. However, I could still use `forEachRemaining{}` which is from `public interface Iterator<E>` of `java.util;` package. i.e.

```
{
    /**
     * Returns {@code true} if the iteration has more elements.
     * (In other words, returns {@code true} if {@link #next} would
     * return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
     *
     * @return {@code true} if the iteration has more elements
     */
    boolean hasNext();

    /**
     * Returns the next element in the iteration.
     *
     * @return the next element in the iteration
     * @throws NoSuchElementException if the iteration has no more elements
     */
    E next();

    /**
     * Removes from the underlying collection the last element returned
     * by this iterator (optional operation).  This method can be called
     * only once per call to {@link #next}.  The behavior of an iterator
     * is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the
     * iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this
     * method.
     *
     * @implSpec
     * The default implementation throws an instance of
     * {@link UnsupportedOperationException} and performs no other action.
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the {@code remove}
     *         operation is not supported by this iterator
     *
     * @throws IllegalStateException if the {@code next} method has not
     *         yet been called, or the {@code remove} method has already
     *         been called after the last call to the {@code next}
     *         method
     */
    default void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("remove");
    }

    /**
     * Performs the given action for each remaining element until all elements
     * have been processed or the action throws an exception.  Actions are
     * performed in the order of iteration, if that order is specified.
     * Exceptions thrown by the action are relayed to the caller.
     *
     * @implSpec
     * <p>The default implementation behaves as if:
     * <pre>{@code
     *     while (hasNext())
     *         action.accept(next());
     * }</pre>
     *
     * @param action The action to be performed for each element
     * @throws NullPointerException if the specified action is null
     * @since 1.8
     */
    default void forEachRemaining(Consumer<? super E> action) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(action);
        while (hasNext())
            action.accept(next());
    }
}
```

How could the `iterator()` have access to both `Iterator` of `Kotlin.collections` package as well as `java.util;` package? Did I miss something?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#mapped-types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some classes from Kotlin standard library are mapped to platform-specific classes (e.g. to Java classes for Kotlin/JVM) automatically. This is the case for `Iterator` you've mentioned.

Note that collection-related classes don't have one-to-one mapping. Kotlin's [`kotlin.collection.Iterator`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-iterator/) only contains read-only operations as you've mentioned in the question. It has sibling interface [`kotlin.collection.MutableIterator`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-iterator/) which extends `Iterator` and adds `remove()` method. Both of these are mapped into Java's [`java.util.Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). So all the Kotlin code, including extension methods like `forEachRemaining`, is declared using Kotlin types, but Java ones would be used under the hood.

When you are passing both Kotlin `k.c.Iterator<T>` and `k.c.MutableIterator<T>` to Java code, it sees usual Java `j.u.Iterator<T>`. When you are passing `j.u.Iterator<T>` to Kotlin code, it sees so-called [*platform type*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#notation-for-platform-types) `(Mutable)Iterator<T>!`. This means that

1. You are free to declare it both nullable and non-null depending on the passing code Javadoc or usage, hence `!` in type name.
2. You can use it as both `MutableIterator` and `Iterator` depending on your use-case.

Motivation behind this mapping as opposed to entirely separate collections in standard library as it's done in Scala, for example, is simple. You don't have to do any copying when mapping between Java and Kotlin worlds. The downside is additional complexity of implementation, which we mostly don't see as users.

See [Java interoperability](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html) section of Kotlin documentation for additional details.